How can Writer Speed be Enhanced
The following reads bytes in a file and writes these bytes as characters in another file using Writer. I have extracted it from this discussion
        String filePath = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("TestDB.db");
        FileSystemStorage fss = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        InputStream is = fss.openInputStream(filePath);
        byte[] plainBytes = Util.readInputStream(is);

        //encrypt database file content

        Log.p("Starting file encryption...");

        byte[] cipherByteArray = FilesCipher.encryptFile(plainBytes);

        Log.p("Done encrypting file");

        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cipherByteArray);

        String encryptedFilePath = fss.getAppHomePath() + "EncryptedDB.db";

        Log.p("Writing to new a file started..."); 

        try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(fss.openOutputStream(encryptedFilePath), "ISO-8859-1")) {
            int nextChar = byteArrayInputStream.read();
            while (nextChar > -1) {
                char[] charArray = {(char) nextChar};
                w.write(charArray);
                nextChar = byteArrayInputStream.read();
            }

            Log.p("Done writing to a new file");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.p("Error " + e);
        }

If file size of the file being read (Eg TestDB.db) is small (less than 500KB), In Simulator & Device, the Writer writes to the new file (Eg. EncryptedDB.db) very fast.
If the file is large eg. 3MB, In Simulator it's written very fast to the new file. But in a device it takes more than 2 minutes. I tested in Android 10.
I have confirmed that encryption is very fast since even when file is large, Log.p("Writing to new a file started..."); is executed within 2 Seconds even in the device.
When file is large, in a Simulator Log.p("Done writing to a new file"); is executed within seconds but in a device it takes more than 3 minutes. This means Writer is slow in a device.
Writer doesn't have a function to write bytes directly.
How can Writer speed be enhanced in devices?

Writing/reading a single character has always been slow. You need to use a buffer and read with power of two multiples (our default is 8192 if I recall correctly).
You're allocating a single character array 3M times on a device... The fact that it runs reasonably well on a desktop is amazing.
I think the writing is the most important part here:
// before the loop
char[] charArray = new char[cipherByteArray.length];
int size = 0;

int nextChar = byteArrayInputStream.read();
// in the loop code...
while (nextChar > -1) {
     charArray[size] = (char)nextChar;
     size++;
     if(size == charArray.length) {
         w.write(charArray);
         size = 0;
     }
     nextChar = byteArrayInputStream.read();
}


// then after the loop is complete...
if(size > 0) {
    w.write(charArray, 0, size);
}

This absolutely enhances Writer speed. A file of size 11.9MB (It has images stored as blob), results to the following log in Android Studio. Encryption completes in 3 sec & writes to the new file in 1 sec
2024-07-28 11:03:08.375 28314-28444 {App Name}        D  [EDT] 0:0:42,937 - Starting file encryption...
2024-07-28 11:03:08.416 28314-28330 {App ID}          I  Background young concurrent copying GC freed 10(31KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(8196KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 43MB/43MB, paused 131us total 112.118ms
2024-07-28 11:03:09.839 28314-28330 {App ID}          I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 1947(87KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(21MB) LOS objects, 36% free, 41MB/65MB, paused 133us total 117.032ms
2024-07-28 11:03:11.031 28314-28444 {App Name}        D  [EDT] 0:0:45,594 - File encryption DONE
2024-07-28 11:03:11.034 28314-28444 {App Name}        D  [EDT] 0:0:45,597 - Saving encrypted file...
2024-07-28 11:03:11.177 28314-28330 {App ID}          I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 18(24KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(28MB) LOS objects, 33% free, 47MB/71MB, paused 231us total 104.218ms
2024-07-28 11:03:12.454 28314-28444 {App Name}        D  [EDT] 0:0:47,17 - DONE Saving encrypted file


I also think that using buffer can enhance this speed. Can you please share a sample which uses buffer that reads with power of two?

Added some sample code

This is great. It can also be applied here to enhance speed at which images are written to a pdf document.

From this Shared Files blog it's also possible to write file bytes directly using OutputStream. That is
OutputStream outputStream = fss.openOutputStream(encryptedFilePath);
outputStream.write(cipherByteArray);

A file of size 11.9MB (It has images stored as blob), results to the following log in Android Studio. Encryption completes in 2 sec & writes to the new file in milliseconds
2024-07-28 11:14:21.109 30329-30415 {App Name}           D  [EDT] 0:0:30,313 - Starting file encryption...
2024-07-28 11:14:23.733 30329-30415 {App Name}           D  [EDT] 0:0:32,937 - File encryption DONE
2024-07-28 11:14:23.735 30329-30415 {App Name}           D  [EDT] 0:0:32,940 - Saving encrypted file...
2024-07-28 11:14:23.767 30329-30415 {App Name}           D  [EDT] 0:0:32,971 - DONE Saving encrypted file

